# How to login and keep cookie for later use of a webpage

Tags: android

So, I have this webpage which I want to access, but first I have to login from another webpage. I want to keep the cookies and then use it for later automatic login. So far what I did:

First, this is the login webpage: https://autenticacao.uvanet.br/autenticacao/pages/login.jsf

It's my university's student's area.

```
public class Consulta extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(100000);

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> val = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        val.add(new BasicNameValuePair("form:usuario", "myusername"));
        val.add(new BasicNameValuePair("form:senha", "mypass"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(val));


        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

        InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String s = "";

        while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(s);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

This is the class I use to make the HttpPost and this is how I call it:

```
@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try{
                        String html = new Consulta().execute("https://autenticacao.uvanet.br/autenticacao/pages/login.jsf").get();
                        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
                        Element link = doc.select("title").first();
                        String t = link.text();
                        tv1.setText(t);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

I believed it would work this way:

1. I send the webpage to login to Consulta.java
2. The class would get the fields "form:usuario" and "form:senha" and fill them with myusername and mypassword and then login
3. The class would return me html code of the second webpage as string

But what happens is that it returns me the first webpage (the login one). I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what, could someone help me? Also, sorry for my english, it's not my main language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do the login (in https://autenticacao.uvanet.br/autenticacao/pages/login.jsf), I don't think the response is the html code of the second webpage. Are you sure about this?

I think the normal behavior for a login page is to respond with the same page (the login one) but adding the session cookie and the header to do a redirect to the second webpage, but not the second page itself.
In this case, you have to read the http header response to extract these parameters: the cookies and the URL of the second webpage.

Using the object HttpResponse:

```
Header[] h = response.getAllHeaders();
```

But I recommend you to use HttpURLConnection class instead of DefaultHttpClient.